# Не собирается офф. пример от Google на Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Склонировал репозиторий:
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/

Пытаюсь запустить в Android Studio, ничего не изменял. Не собирается, получаю ошибки:

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-controllerclient/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-controller:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-controllerclient/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-simplepanowidget/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-simplevideowidget/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-treasurehunt/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-audio:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-treasurehunt/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(43, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-videoplayer/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(42, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-videoplayer/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

В чем проблема? Google не помогает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй заменить в каждом файле build.gradle

```java
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-audio:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.+'
}
```

Скорее всего вылетит после компиляции сообщение об обновлении, обновился и ошибки ушли.

Comment: спасибо большое, работает. Вернул после обновления 1.60.0 тоже работает.